# Python Script Errors

Tags: python, maya

I am doing a simple `Python` script in `Maya`, and I'm constantly getting syntax errors.  What needs to be changed in my script?

```
select = ls(sl)
if (len(sel) == 0):
    error("Nothing was selected.")
else:
    rotate - relative 1 2 3
    scale - relative 4 5 6
    translate - relative 7 8 9
```

Comment: Can u put error here for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: The last three lines aren't Python.  `rotate - relative 1 2 3` is basically the expression `rotate - relative`, i.e. `rotate` minus `relative`, followed by three numbers that cause a syntax error.  What do you want to do with the numbers at the end?

Comment: What is `rotate - relative 1 2 3` ???

Comment: Is that the code? You should probably start with [\[Python\]: The Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html#the-python-tutorial) or [\[TutorialsPoint\]: Python - Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.sphere(n='sphere1')
select = cmds.ls(selection=True)

if (len(select)==0):
    cmds.error("Nothing was selected.")
else:
    cmds.xform(r=True, ro=(0, 90, 0))
    cmds.xform(r=True, s=(1.2, 1.5, 0.5))
    cmds.xform(r=True, t=(-9, 3, 0))
```